# How to create a continous-date chart grouping by days out of Mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a chart with continous dates in x-axis from minimum date to maximum date; and count per each day.

I have this table:

```
ID  Date      
==============
1   2018-01-05    
2   2018-01-05
3   2018-01-07
4   2018-01-08
5   2018-01-08
```

This is what I have but I am unable to get the continous dates

```
$sql = "SELECT date,COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY date";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $x_axis[] = $row['date'];
    $values[] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
}
```

Example of desired result would be (I want to get a zero when there are no records for that middle date):

```
2018-01-05 => 2
2018-01-06 => 0
2018-01-07 => 1
2018-01-08 => 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$finaldata = array();
$sql = "SELECT date, COUNT(*) total FROM ( SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date ASC) AS sub GROUP BY date";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $x_axis[] = $row['date'];
    $values[] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
}

for($date = $x_axis[0]; strtotime($date) <= strtotime(end($x_axis)); ) {
    $key = array_search($date, $x_axis);
    $finaldata[$date] = $key === FALSE ? 0 : $values[$key];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)))
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($finaldata);die;
```

Your final data is in `$finaldata` array